# Using a button on a copied sheet to open the linked form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So the situation is that I have a script published as a web app that creates a copy of a spreadsheet into the google drive of the person who clicked it and opens it up.

There is a form attached to this spreadsheet that gets copied correctly. What I want is to have a button (drawing with a script attached) that when clicked will launch the google form in the same way as if the person had clicked 'Form > go to live form'.

I tried getting the form ID as follows (got this from another SO question):

```
var formUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getFormUrl();
var formID = formUrl.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
```

However I do not believe that this is the id for the live version of the form, nor can I work out a way to put this id into a URL that will work. (I'm pretty sure this is the id for the form which you go to by clicking Form > edit form)

Answer (score 1):

You can't link directly from a drawing, but you can use Apps Script to serve a popup which includes a link to the form. Here's a sample:

```js
function showForm() {
  // Helper function gets the live URL for the form
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form = sheet.getFormUrl();

  showAnchor(form, "Google Form");
}

function showAnchor(url, name) {
  // Build some simple HTML and display
  var html = '<html><body><a href="'+url+'" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">'+name+'</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");
}
```

The other option is to include a styled cell that can serve as a "button" to the form. It removes the extra step of showing the popup to click on. That is as simple as writing a dynamic `hyperlink` formula:

```
function showForm() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form = sheet.getFormUrl();

  sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2,1).setValue('=hyperlink("' + form + '", "Open Form")');
}
```